# Find which widget has focus in Ruby 2.3.3

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

In Python, I use:

```py
who = widget.focus_get()
```

and in Perl:

```perl
$who = $widget->focusCurrent;
```

to tell me which widget has the focus. So:

1. What is the equivalent code in Ruby under Linux?
2. Is there a good book or article about low-level Ruby Tk? All the articles I have seen only cover the simplistic stuff.

Comment: The short answer is that at least for my purposes (see my comment to MarkDBlackwell's answer): Tk.focus will return the address of the of the TK object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [T]o tell me which widget has the focus[...w]hat is the equivalent code in Ruby under Linux?

Fairly equivalently, if you have three Tk objects (for example), then you can say (in Ruby):

```rb
array = [tk_object_1, tk_object_2, tk_object_3]
path = Tk.focus.path
index = array.find_index {|e| e.path == path}
object = array.at index
```

EDIT: Or, more simply:

```rb
object = Tk.focus
```

Here's how to determine which object (of your many Tk objects) this is:

```rb
array = [tk_object_1, tk_object_2, tk_object_3]
index = array.find_index {|e| e == object}
```

(End of edit.)

I managed to locate documentation for the `focus` method (in both the
[Ruby wrapper](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.5/libdoc/tk/rdoc/Tk.html#method-c-focus)
and the original
[Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/focus.htm))
and for the `path` method (in the
[Ruby wrapper](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.5/libdoc/tk/rdoc/TkObject.html#method-i-path)).

I wrote a program which demonstrates setting and getting the focus:

```rb
require 'tk'

def focus_array
  @focus_array ||= [
      f_content, e_content,
      to_one,    e_one,
      to_two,    e_two,
      ]
end

def focus_array_class_width_max
  @focus_array_class_width_max ||= focus_array.map {|e| e.class.to_s.length}.max
end

def focus_delay
  milliseconds = 1000
  Tk.after milliseconds, lambda_focus_rotate
  nil
end

def focus_force(object)
  force = true
  Tk.focus_to object, force
  nil
end

def focus_print
  path = Tk.focus.path
  index = focus_array.find_index {|e| e.path == path}
  s = klass_justified index
  puts "Item #{index}'s class and path are:  #{s}  #{path}"
  nil
end

def focus_rotate
  @counter += 1
  index = @counter % focus_array.length
  puts '' if 0 == index
  focus_force focus_array.at index
  nil
end

def klass_justified(index)
  focus_array.at(index).class.to_s.ljust focus_array_class_width_max
end

def lambda_focus_rotate
  @lambda_focus_rotate ||= Kernel.lambda do
    focus_rotate
    focus_print
    focus_delay
  end
end

def main
  root.title = 'Root'
  objects_create
  @counter = -1 # Start before first.
  focus_delay
  Tk.mainloop
  nil
end

def objects_create
# Keep order:
  e_content
  e_one
  e_two
  nil
end

def spacing_set(object)
  object.width 7
  object.grid padx: 40
end

#-------------
# Tk objects:

def e_content
  @e_content ||= begin
    e = Tk::Tile::Entry.new f_content
    spacing_set e
  end
end

def e_one
  @e_one ||= begin
    e = Tk::Tile::Entry.new to_one
    spacing_set e
  end
end

def e_two
  @e_two ||= begin
    e = Tk::Tile::Entry.new to_two
    spacing_set e
  end
end

def f_content
  $f_content ||= begin
    f = Tk::Tile::Frame.new root
    f.grid
  end
end

def root
  $root ||= TkRoot.new
end

def to_one
  @to_one ||= TkToplevel.new f_content
end

def to_two
  @to_two ||= TkToplevel.new f_content
end

main
```

It works for me using Ruby 2.2.5 (with Tk 8.5.12) on Windows 7.

> Is there a good book or article about low-level Ruby Tk? All the articles I have seen only cover the simplistic stuff.

To my knowledge, no one has written a thorough description of Ruby's wrapper for Tk (at least, not in English). However, we have the wrapper's
[RDoc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.5/libdoc/tk/rdoc/)
documentation, and we can read books describing how to use Tk from other languages. I think the best one (for Ruby purposes) is *Learning Perk/Tk* by Nancy Walsh (1999). Here are its links at
[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565923146),
[Alibris](http://www.alibris.com/Learning-Perl-TK-Nancy-Walsh/book/28329527)
and
[O'Reilly](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565923140.do) (along with its [example code](http://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9781565923140)).

Also we can `grep` the wrapper's library source code (since it's installed on our computers).

Doing so for the constant `TkToplevel` (for example) leads to the file `/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tk/toplevel.rb` (or wherever that file resides on your system).

In that file, searching (for the string `TkToplevel`) reveals that the constant seems to be defined as an alias for class `Tk::Toplevel`, which is documented
[here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.5/libdoc/tk/rdoc/Tk/Toplevel.html).

Ultimately it takes fairly difficult effort to investigate how to do unusual things in Ruby with Tk.

Good results regarding particular issues have been obtained by asking on the
[Ruby forum](http://www.ruby-forum.com).

The
[TkDocs](http://tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html)
tutorial is very helpful, along with the Tcl-language
[Tk commands](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/contents.htm)
reference documentation.

Comment: Excellent! For my purposes (five cells arranged in a spreadsheet-like fashion), Tk.focus (without the ".path") returns the address of the TK object so I can do things like: x = Tk.focus; x.delete(0, :end); x.insert(0, :x) to replace the contents of a cell with an 'x'

Comment: I have Mastering Perl/Tk by Lidie and Walsh, which is great.

Comment: @Jorgen I have edited my answer to reflect that `Tk.focus` is the equivalent you asked for.

Comment: @Jorgen As you may know, both books _Learning Perl/Tk_ and _Mastering Perl/Tk_ describe only the Perl Tk module, which eschews Tcl. Instead, Ruby's Tk wrapper is a thin wrapper over Tk's own Tcl code, as is the newer Perl Tkx module, described at [meta::cpan](http://metacpan.org/pod/Tkx) and [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=846156). These can utilize the improved graphical look of Tk version 8.5, per the [TkDocs tutorial](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html#walkthrough) (if you select Perl).

Comment: Thanks, yes, I come from Perl and Python. I got the above Ruby solution from your excellent link to the tcl/tk documentation plus what I learned from your above code. In Perl widget->focus() sets the focus and returns nothing. In tcl/tk focus() returns the address I was looking for. Thanks again! I would never have found the solution without your answer!